# How do I put a variable in http_build_query?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude of an address but don't know how to put a variable in http build query.
I basically want to get the lat and long of place and get figure out how to put a variable in http_build_query.

**This is what I tried:**

```
$queryString = http_build_query([
            'access_key' => 'API_KEY',
            'query' => $place,
            'country' => 'US',
            'region' => 'California',
            'output' => 'json',
            'limit' => 1,
            ]);

            $ch = curl_init(sprintf('%s?%s', 'http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward', $queryString));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $json = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            $apiResult = json_decode($json, true);

            print_r($apiResult);

            foreach($apiResult as $result) {
                foreach($result as $answer) {
                    $pickuplat = htmlspecialchars($answer['latitude']);
                    $pickuplong = htmlspecialchars($answer['longitude']);
                }
            }
```

**Example without the var**

```
$queryString = http_build_query([
            'access_key' => 'API_KEY',
            'query' => '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW',
            'country' => 'US',
            'region' => 'California',
            'output' => 'json',
            'limit' => 1,
            ]);

            $ch = curl_init(sprintf('%s?%s', 'http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward', $queryString));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $json = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            $apiResult = json_decode($json, true);

            print_r($apiResult);

            foreach($apiResult as $result) {
                foreach($result as $answer) {
                    $pickuplat = htmlspecialchars($answer['latitude']);
                    $pickuplong = htmlspecialchars($answer['longitude']);
                }
            }
```

Please help!

Comment: `'query' => $place,` is the right way to do it. What's the problem?

Comment: I won't go with building the string to create the URL. You can can pass `CURL_POSTFIELDS` to the curl options.